# Most Popular Fonts used in  Webpages and their Fallbacks?

Tags: css, fonts

This is a two part question, the second question is dependent on the first:

1. What are the most popular fonts used on web pages? (the top half dozen will suffice).
2. Include the proper CSS fallbacks for the above fonts.

The reason I ask is that I have to build a form that will allow webmasters to choose a CSS font from a drop-down menu. The site will take the chosen string (fonts with respective fallbacks) from a database and insert it (via php) into aspects of a page.

**Edit**: Just passing this on. Although not scientific in its approach to what constitutes 'popular' fonts and respective fallback combinations, this was a helpful starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: What's a CSS font? I've never heard of such things.

Comment: http://www.basictemplates.com/blog/2005/08/most-common-fonts-used-on-web-page.shtml

Comment: Bolt Clock, I edited the question.

Comment: @BoltClock: [Curtis CSS Typeface](http://desandro.com/resources/curtis-css-typeface/)

Comment: friends don't let friends use w3schools; see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this list useful: [WindowsMacFonts](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html).

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is [Code Style's font survey](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/). They have data on the most commonly installed fonts for each of Windows, Mac and Linux (plus a Java app you can use to contribute your data) and suggested font lists for serif, sans-serif plus a few more.

Comment: Doesn't Code Style's page tell you about the client's computer, not which are most used in actual webpages?

Comment: You're right, I guess I misread the first part of the question. It does cover the second part at least: fallback fonts for a given style. (But a list of fonts that's going to work is more useful than a list of what's popular, isn't it?)

Comment: I think so Jared. Thanks for your comment above. That is half of it.

Comment: @Rup - That was my first link in a comment, then I realized it wasn't right, so I deleted it. @John R - As far as fallback, there are several different ways to think about it. `times new roman` fallback could be `serif` or `Georgia`, `Verdana` could be `sans serif` which might be `Arial` or `Helvetica`. It's tough to tell you what to do. I suggest reading the articles on A List Apart: http://www.alistapart.com/.

Comment: @Rup - And I agree with your comment edit. :)

Comment: @Rup: +1 still for the great link!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its difficlut to measure the Popularity if FONT but inmost business, propfessonal site will use Font Family such as 
**Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;**  very much . its elegant and yet simple